# find indices where one array is larger than an element in a second array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])
b = np.array([0,5,10,15])
```

I want an output array with the length of `b` where each element `b[i]` is the index of the first element of `a` which is at least `b[i]`:

```
out = np.array([0, 5, 10, 15]
```

A slow solution is:

```
out = []
for x in b: 
    i = np.argmax( a >= x )
    out.append( i )
```

and this is a marginal speed increase:

```
out = []
i=0
for x in b: 
    i = np.argmax( a[i:] >= x ) + i
    out.append( i )
```

Any ideas for a pure numpy solution? This is prohibitively slow. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` is sorted, you can use `a.searchsorted(b)`.

Comment: thanks @Bi Rico! works great. Amazing the speed difference on `3e6` elements

Comment: In addition to being "pure numpy", `searchsorted` uses a binary search so it scales much better with the size of `a`. It's O(log(N)) instead of O(N).